# Stored selector doesn't work correctly with each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Below is a recreation of the problem I'm having. I stored `$('.box')` into the `$box` variable. In my actual code, I'm using `$box` in many places to do things and it works fine, except in the portion of code below, where I tried to use loop through the many `$box`'s on the page with jQuery's `each()`. I've read the jQuery documentation on `each()` and it *looks* like it should work. My best guess is that storing the object into a variable stores the first element the DOM sees and jQuery can't iterate over a single element, but can someone with more knowledge explain why this doesn't work?

HTML:

```
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.button {
  user-select: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
```

JS:

```
var $box = $('.box');
$('.button').on('click', function() {

  $($box).each(function(i) {  // Why does this work?
  //$box.each(function(i) {    // But this doesn't?

    $(this).append(i);

  });
});
```

Here's the same code above on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dustindowell/pen/vEVeKj)

EDIT: As one of the answers pointed out, there was a flaw in my example code that made it appear that this didn't work, when in fact it does. I've updated my code and my Codepen to fix the example. There must be something else in my JS causing this not to work.

Comment: Is the assignment of `$box` inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: You should put the non-working code in the Codepen, not the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code   .  you already assign $('.box') object to $box  see here working code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je3qwft6/)

```
var $box = $('.box');
$('.button').on('click', function() {
 $box.each(function(i) {  // Why does this work?
//$box.each(function() {    // But this doesn't?
   $(this).append(i);
 });
});
```

Comment: You should explain the change you made, which was to add the `i` argument to the `.each()` callback function.

Comment: You're right. I missed that. Thanks. There must be something else in my code causing this not to work for me.

Comment: have you added jquery lib file? or add code in $(document).ready(function())